# Python Loss of data when running threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have two versions of the same program with the same task, one that utilizes the threading module while the other doesn't. The task I want to optimize is the following

```
from random import randint
import time

t = time.time()

rolls = 25000
wins = 0
loss = 0

while rolls > 0:
    dice1 = randint(1, 6)
    dice2 = randint(1, 6)

    if dice1+dice2 == 11 or dice1+dice2 == 7 or dice1 == dice2:
        wins += 1
    else:
        loss += 1

    rolls -= 1

print(wins+loss)
percentage = (wins / wins+loss) * 100

print("Calculated percentage of a roll fulfilling requirements are:", 
round(percentage, 2), "%")
print(round((time.time()-t), 3))
```

As you can hopefully tell I basically want to roll two dices a certain amount of times, in this example that number is 25 000 and then print out what the chance that these two dice fulfill one of the three criteria, sum is 11, sum is 7 or they both have the same number.

Of course the amount of rolls I decide to go with alters the outcome of this program by giving a more accurate answer the higher you go. All well and good up until this point, program working as expected and the sum of wins and loss is equal to total amount of rolls.

What bothers me is the threaded version of the program. When I enter say, 25 000 rolls there too I end up with the sum of around 22 000 for wins + loss (this sum varies from run to run, why are there rolls disappearing?) Another side effect from running the threaded version is a less accurate calculation of the win percentage.

```
from random import randint
import threading
import time

t = time.time()

def dice_calc(rolls):
    global wins
    global loss
    while rolls > 0:

        dice1 = randint(1, 6)
        dice2 = randint(1, 6)

        if dice1+dice2 == 11 or dice1+dice2 == 7 or dice1 == dice2:
            wins += 1
        else:
            loss += 1

        rolls -= 1

wins = 0
loss = 0
rolls = 25000

t1 = threading.Thread(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4,))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4,))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4,))
t4 = threading.Thread(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4,))

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()

print(wins+loss)

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()

percentage = (wins / (wins+loss)) * 100

print("Calculated percentage of a roll fulfilling requirements are:", 
round(percentage, 2), "%")

print(round((time.time()-t), 3))
```

My aim with using this threading module was to increase the programs accuracy while taking up less processing time. I have managed to do the exact opposite.

How is this possible and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You need to use locks, because if two or more threads and they have access to the same code with the same variables, they are going to mess up their data. I need to review the slides I got from my class to give you a complete answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def dice_calc(rolls):

    mutex.acquire() #Since you are using global variables you need to lock the code before the thread has access to the global

    global wins
    global loss
    while rolls > 0:

        dice1 = randint(1, 6)
        dice2 = randint(1, 6)

        if dice1+dice2 == 11 or dice1+dice2 == 7 or dice1 == dice2:
            wins += 1
        else:
            loss += 1

        rolls -= 1

    mutex.release() #Then you release it when it is finished
```

You need to lock the code before the thread has access to the global, then you release it after it is done processing.

A good analogy:

You and three friends want a drink out of the water fountain, you each need to wait your turn to use it before you are able to take a drink. If you each go at the same time it will get messy because there is only one water fountain. The water fountain are your global variables and code, you and your friends are the threads

Comment: I did what you said and while it didn't solve the problem entirely it did make the program run more consistently. At 25 000 rolls I now get 18 750 as the sum of wins + loss every time the code is run. Any more insight as to why I'm not getting a 100% of the rolls back as "wins" and "loss"?

Comment: @ToastyEngineer Oh yep, looking through my C code for multi-threading I used something called a volatile unsigned int as my global. The problem definitely has to do with using global variables. Try doing a double acquire and a double release, maybe that will work?

Comment: Using double acquire and double release started an infinite loop.

Comment: Nevermind, figured out why I got strange results... I had accidentally written the print(wins+loss) piece of code before i joined all the threads.

Comment: @ToastyEngineer oops, I didn't even see that part

Comment: I am still uncertain of some things... like why am I not seeing any performance gain in threaded mode vs non-threaded mode? Doesn't having more threads allow the program to utilize more cpu processing power?

Comment: @ToastyEngineer That's a bit complicated. With CPU heavy tasks you might not always see a gain in performance especially if using locks because it prevents the other threads from doing work at the same time. So when you need to optimize your locks, but at the same time its like running the code on one core because of the locks. If you want to run the code in parallel you will need to use multiprocessing. This is where you are able to split up the work and run the exact same code with different processes and to speed it up. Then using both at the same time gets even more complicated

Comment: Alright so I tried changing from the threading module to the multiprocessing module. I changed some of my code to what (i think?) is right. https://pastebin.com/TQtnLDF2
However, this results in an output that I don't understand... Maybe you can help me understand?
Output is as follows:

0.011 (should be wins + loss)

0 (no idea what this is)

0.588 (time, the only one that doesn't weird me out)